# Stop WndProc processing during shutdown of the app

Tags: windows, delphi, message-queue, c++builder, postmessage

I have defined a `WndProc` which looks similar to below (the code is written in C++Builder, but it applies in similar form to Delphi as well):

```cpp
#define WM_SETTINGS_UPDATE WM_APP + 1234
#define WM_GUI_UPDATE      WM_APP + 1235

void __fastcall TForm1::WndProc(TMessage &fMessage)
{
switch (fMessage.Msg)
    {
    default:                 break;

    case WM_SETTINGS_UPDATE: ProcessMySettingsUpdate();
                             fMessage.Result = 1;
                             return;
                             break; // I know this is not needed, I do this purely for aesthetics

    case WM_GUI_UPDATE:      ProcessMyGUIUpdate();
                             fMessage.Result = 1;
                             return;
                             break; // I know this is not needed, I do this purely for aesthetics
    }

TForm::WndProc(fMessage);
}
```

So in essence this:

1. checks for my custom `WM_APP` range messages (`WM_SETTINGS_UPDATE` and `WM_GUI_UPDATE`) in this case.
2. processes those messages and then sets `fMessage.Result` to `1` indicating message was processed and returns (avoiding `TForm:WndProc(fMessage)`, which I understand is the same as `inherited` in Delphi, and not needed if the message is processed).
3. if my messages are not processed, it just calls `TForm:WndProc(fMessage)` (or `inherited`) to do the default processing.

My concern is this - what if there is a situation where the application is shutting down, and there are still some messages being unprocessed (left in the message queue by `PostMessage()`)?

What I'd like to do in such a situation is to avoid calling my own processing, as it might result in some uninitialized memory Access Violations or similar. Is this basically enough, or do I need to apply some special processing to avoid that kind of situation, or process some "application shutting down" code?

And also - do I need to call `inherited` / `TForm:WndProc(fMessage)` after I am done with my processing, or is it safe to do it like above (set `Result` to 1 and return)?

Note - this does not necessarily apply to the `MainForm` (the first Form being created).

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what if there is a situation where the application is shutting down, and there are still some messages being unprocessed (left in the message queue by `PostMessage()`)?

That is perfectly OK.  Once a Form's `HWND` is destroyed, any remaining messages that were posted for that window will simply be discarded when dispatched by the main message loop.  Your `WndProc` will not be called for them.

> What I'd like to do in such a situation is to avoid calling my own processing, as it might result in some uninitialized memory Access Violations or similar.

That should not be a concern.  One, because messages won't be dispatched to your Form's `HWND` after it is destroyed, and two, when the `MainForm` is closed, the main message loop is signaled to stop running, before any active Form `HWND`s are destroyed.  So, there won't be any further message dispatching anyway.

> Is this basically enough, or do I need to apply some special processing to avoid that kind of situation

It should be enough.  You typically do not need to handle this special (unless your custom messages are carrying pointers to objects that have to be freed).

> or process some "application shutting down" code?

If you really want to detect when the app is being shut down, try having your `WndProc` handle the `WM_CLOSE` message (or you can use the Form's `OnClose/Query` events).

> do I need to call `inherited` / `TForm:WndProc(fMessage)` after I am done with my processing, or is it safe to do it like above (set `Result` to 1 and return)?

That is perfectly OK for custom messages.